# In R, is there a difference between the types which would elsewhere be Int and Vector[Int]?

Tags: r, types

I'm trying to understand the type system in R.

Most modern programming languages have a type system in which there is a difference between the numeric type `int` and the container type `Vector[int]` (a.k.a. `int vector`, `Vector int`, `vector<int>`, etc.). In R, if I run

```
x <- 1L
typeof(x)
is.vector(x)

y <- c(1L,2L)
typeof(y)
is.vector(y)
```

I get out

> ```
> [1] "integer"
> [1] TRUE
> [1] "integer"
> [1] TRUE
> ```

This suggests that there is no distinct 'int' type and every integer is a vector (of ints). Is that right?

Comment: You can test integer with `is.integer`. Vector is the structure and integer the class of values for me

Comment: @Clemsang That returns true in both cases too...

Comment: In R a single value is a vector of length 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between a value and a vector of length 1 in general in R (integer or not):

```
identical(1L, c(1L))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Cheers. Why did you use 'identical' and not '==', please?

Comment: Also, does that mean every list is a list of vectors?

Comment: 1) `identical` is safer for exact comparisons, please have a look at the documentation that provides great examples. 2) "Almost all lists in R internally are Generic Vectors" according to the help of `list`

Comment: Good answer (+1), though I might add that more precisely, **there is no such thing** as a single (integer/numeric/...) value in R that is *not* a vector of length one. That is "[t]he basic data structure in R **is** the vector": http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html